# UK Visa with Children

Tags: visas, uk, children

Do my children (10 and 11) need to attend the visa interview at the Embassy; or can I represent them?

Comment: Can you please add some more details, such as nationality, type of visa, location you are applying. As your question stands there’s not really enough information to be able to answer it.

Comment: @HankyPanky That question and its answer don't say anything about whether children need to come to the interview.

Comment: @DavidRicherby close-vote retracted.

Comment: **Close voters:** the question "How should a family with young children apply for UK visas?" says nothing at all about whether the children need to come to the interview. This is not a duplicate. (cc @bytebuster)

Comment: What interview? Didn't the UK stop doing visitor visa interviews several years ago?

Comment: @Ryan May we assume you are referring to the biometric appointment? As Michael Hampton says, UKVI does not do ‘interviews’ for Standard Visitor Visas.

Comment: User has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.